# how to export intellij project

Tags: intellij-idea, import, export, project

I simply want to export my java intellij project from one pc to another, no need for git because I only want to test something on the other pc because it has more memory.
Surprisingly no information on this is available, there is information on how to export a project to a jar file, but I cannot import from this jar file. On their website : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/import-existing-sources-project-name-and-location.html they don't give any clear instructions on how to do this simple operation? how is this done?

Comment: Copy the project folder, that is all. See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544839.

Comment: I just compressed the project folder, sent it to other pc, and tried to open a new project from existing sources with this compressed project folder, but is says : "cannot import anything from ...". 
Any other ideas?

Comment: There must be `.idea` directory and `.iml` files.

Comment: Yes, they should be in it, since it's the project folder?

Comment: It depends on how the project was created. It's possible to keep these files outside of the root with sources. So ensure that these files were copied, then just Open and point to a directory that has `.idea` subdirectory inside.

Comment: How do I ensure these are copied?

Comment: I don't know how to answer this question.

Comment: Can I not simply export and import? This is overly complicated for one of the simplest of tasks, Intellij really dropped in my estimation

Comment: There is nothing easier than copying a folder with all the files from one system to another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Till version 2016.3.4 IntelliJ doesn't provide such facility.

Best way to do so would be to copy the whole directory containing your project or module. Doing this would retain all your project related settings.

Answer (score 0):

With the latest version of IntelliJ IDEA, all you need to do is unzip the project in the new computer and then select Open in the IntelliJ IDEA new project wizard. Do not use the option to import the project from the zip file, as that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Take all directories of your project and copy them into the other computer. Launch `IntelliJ` and open the folder of your main directory project, that is all it needs to work (*.iml files do all stuff for you). If you don't know what directory is the main, you can close the project in your other IDE and see what paths it is catching. For example in my case:

[image: IntellIj Welcome View]